# How to fetch multiple records from the table using stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following table and records

```
create table Employees (emp_id number, emp_name varchar2(50), hire_date date, department_id number) ;

insert into Employees values(1,'ALex','21-06-07',10),
                            (2,'Duplex','21-06-08',20),
                            (3,'Charles','21-06-09',30),
                            (4,'Demon','21-06-06',40);
```

Requirement : I want to take Hire_date as an input and display all the records of the employees who has joined post the hire_date using stored procedure.

Example : Hire_date is 21-06-07

Then output should be

```
2,Duplex, '21-06-08',20
3,Charles, '21-06-09',30
```

Code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE display_records (
    joindate IN DATE
) AS
    lv_name    VARCHAR2(50);
    lv_sal     NUMBER;
    lv_deptid  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        first_name,
        salary,
        department_id
    INTO
        lv_name,
        lv_sal,
        lv_deptid
    FROM
        hr.employees
    WHERE
        hire_date > joindate;

END;
```

Comment: very well said @KoenLostrie

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez Yes I was searching for the same but couldn't get from where should I mark it as answered

Comment: there is an icon in your question ( you  are the only one who can see it ) below the points and arrows that is the one you have to use to accept the answer.

Comment: Also note that your column HIRE_DATE is (as it should be) declared as a DATE data type.  But the value that you provide in your INSERT is not a DATE but a character string that _you_, not oracle, sees as a date.  Please take notice that in the answers provided, the INSERT makes use of the TO_DATE function, to convert the _character string_ to a DATE.  The DATE data type is an internal, binary structure, not readable by humans, and not displayable on the screen nor "enterable" on the keyboard.

Comment: Also asked in https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4488571/how-to-fetch-multiple-records-from-the-table-using-stored-procedure#latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please test your own testcase before posting it. It has syntax errors. Also, there are no columns called "salary" or "first_name" in your table, so those cannot be shown.

Here is a solution.

```
create table employees_x (emp_id number, emp_name varchar2(50), hire_date date, department_id number) ;

insert into employees_x values(1,'ALex',TO_DATE('21-06-07','DD-MM-YY'),10);
insert into employees_x values(2,'Duplex',TO_DATE('21-06-08','DD-MM-YY'),20);
insert into employees_x values(3,'Charles',TO_DATE('21-06-09','DD-MM-YY'),30);
insert into employees_x values(4,'Demon',TO_DATE('21-06-06','DD-MM-YY'),40);
 
 
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE display_records (
    joindate IN DATE
) AS
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM employees_x WHERE hire_date > joindate)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('name: '|| r.emp_name ||', department_id: '|| r.department_id);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

set serveroutput on size 999999

exec display_records(joindate => TO_DATE('01-01-08','DD-MM-YY'));

name: Duplex, department_id: 20
name: Charles, department_id: 30
```

Comment: How to handle exceptions. When I am writing Exception when no_data_found print 'No records'. But this message is not displaying in my code.

Comment: This is a cursor for loop. If the select statement has no rows then it will not raise a NO_DATA_FOUND exception, it will just print no rows. I suggest you give that a try. If you want a message shown if no data is found (which is not an exception), then you could add an additional variable which you set to a value in the loop and print a message based on that variables value. Give it a try before immediately asking for answers - best way to learn